# How to bind combo-box to a certain item in an ObservableCollection list - WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have this code:

```
C#:

public ObservableCollection<My_EDMX_Table> formatsList = new ObservableCollection<My_EDMX_Table>();

XAML:

<ComboBox 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.Column="5" 
    Margin="0, 5, 5, 5" 
    Name="CB_1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding formatsList}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding formatsList[2], Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    IsEnabled="True" 
    Opacity="1" 
    DisplayMemberPath="formatNaziv" 
    SelectionChanged="CB_1_SelectionChanged" />
```

I want to bind certain item in the list, in this case the first element in formatsList. Although the app compiles I don't get my combo box set to a chosen value from its ItemSource list.

What is the right way to bind observable collection and set component to appropriate value?

Comment: Did you assigned an istance of viewmodel class to the DataContext property of the view?

Comment: Post xaml, codebehind and viewmodel clas pls

Comment: This is working..What exactly is your problem? How many items are there in the collection?

Comment: `formatsList` have to be a public property, not a field.

Comment: This will of course not work. The SelectedValue Binding with a fixed index does not work two-way. Why don't you set SelectedIndex to 2?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the right way to bind observable collection and set component to appropriate value?

The right way would be to bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to a source property of the view model that you set to `formatsList[2]` in the view model class.

You don't decide which item that is the "certain" one in the view. It's the view model that decides this and returns the "certain" one that the view then binds to. Remember that your application logic should be implemented in the view model class.

If you always want to bind to the third item initially for some reason, you might as well hardcode the `SelectedIndex` property to `2` in the XAML.